# Input text field to td

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a website that the user will put its  Name and LastName   and it will send the text in the table data . My first inputs is showing in first table data

I need to put the second inputs in the second table data (can someone help me !) lol

```
<h1 align="center">INFORMATION</h1>
Name: <input id="first_name" size="30" type="text">
LastName: <input type="text" size="30" id="lastname">
<button class="okok" name="myBtn" type="submit"  value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">GO </button>
<br />
<table border="2" cellspacing=1 align="center" height="100" width="600"> 
    <tr bgcolor="black">
        <th width="20" style="color:white;">Name</th>
        <th width="20" style="color:white;">Lastname</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>     
        <td style="color:white;" id="firstname"> </td>
        <td style="color:white;" id="firstlastname"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="color:white;" id="secondname"> </td>
        <td style="color:white;" id="secondlastname"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My script

```
function ajax_post(){
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("firstname");
    table.innerText = fn;

    var pre = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var table1 = document.getElementById("firstlastname");
    table1.innerText = pre;
}
```

I have no idea how to get the second input and put it in secondname and secondlastname without creating a new cell !

Comment: You do it in the same way you did the first one. Although you need to add a form input element for getting that data.

Comment: hmm can you tell me how hehehe

Comment: did you mean add new table or you just add the data to the new row?

Comment: add the second input text to the secondname and secondlastname

Comment: Do you have any _server-side_ code or you just want to simply add rows one after each other to the table in the _html_?

Comment: i just want to simply add the second input (textfield) from the user to my second tablerow (secondname ,secondlastname)

Comment: And will you have third and fourth and ... records or you just have first and second row? also will you get the second inputs for the second row from same input fields or from different input fields?

Comment: the first and second row   ... from the same input field      (the second input user input i mean like : i input first :apple and the second one is : orange: like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then, from what you have and what you need I think this can do what you want to do.

But if you could use `jQuery` then we may had easier ways...
(I have changed some 'ids' to simplify the code)

**HTML**

```
<h1 align="center">INFORMATION</h1>
Name: <input id="txtFirstname" type="text" size="30">
<br />
LastName: <input id="txtLastname" type="text" size="30">
<br />
<button class="okok" name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">GO </button>
<br />
<table border="2" cellspacing="1" align="center" height="100" width="600"> 
    <tr bgcolor="black">
        <th width="20" style="color:white;">Name</th>
        <th width="20" style="color:white;">Lastname</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>     
        <td style="color:red;" id="tdFirstname1"> </td>
        <td style="color:red;" id="tdLastname1"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>     
        <td style="color:red;" id="tdFirstname2"> </td>
        <td style="color:red;" id="tdLastname2"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

First I get a JavaScript variable to indicate which row I'm writing the data and set it to 1:

```
var rowNum = 1;
```

and then comes your function with modification:

```
function ajax_post(){
  if(rowNum < 3){
    var txtFirstname = document.getElementById("txtFirstname").value;
    var txtLastname = document.getElementById("txtLastname").value;

    document.getElementById("tdFirstname"+rowNum).innerText = txtFirstname;
    document.getElementById("tdLastname"+rowNum).innerText = txtLastname;

    rowNum++;
  }
}
```

also you can find a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mqs0cj8e/1/)

Comment: It's writing, but because you had set the color to white, you could not see them, so I edited the code and set the color to red so you can see them

Comment: you have given `color` as **white** so it may not display in `td`